# Change nested json estructure from python dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a huge JSON file: `tribunals.json`, that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "city":"05045",
        "tribunals":[
            {"name":"tribunal 1","value":"path_1"}
            ]
    },
    {
        "city":"81001",
        "tribunals":[
            {"name":"tribunal 1","value":"path_1"},
            {"name":"tribunal 2","value":"path_2"},
            {"name":"tribunal 3","value":"path_3"},
            {"name":"tribunal 4","value":"path_4"},
            {"name":"tribunal 5","value":"path_5"},
            {"name":"tribunal 6","value":"path_6"}
            ]
    }
]
```

I want to transform it into this:

```
{
    "05045": 
    {
        "tribunal 1": "path_1"
    },
    "81001":
    {
        "tribunal 1": "path_1",
        "tribunal 2": "path_2",
        "tribunal 3": "path_3",
        "tribunal 4": "path_4",
        "tribunal 5": "path_5",
        "tribunal 6": "path_6"
    }
}
```

I've tried different types of iteration over the JSON to obtain de expected output, but none of them worked. For now, I'm doing this:

```
import json
tribunals = open('tribunals.json',encoding='utf-8')
tribunals = json.load(tribunals)

for tribunal in tribunals:
    print(tribunal['city'])
    for tribunals_list in tribunal['tribunals']:
        print(tribunals_list)
```

This gives me the next output

```
05045
{"name":"tribunal 1", "value":"path_1"}
81001
{"name":"tribunal 1","value": "path_1"}
{"name":"tribunal 2","value": "path_2"}
{"name":"tribunal 3","value": "path_3"}
{"name":"tribunal 4","value": "path_4"}
{"name":"tribunal 5","value": "path_5"}
{"name":"tribunal 6","value": "path_6"}
```

and based on this I'm finishing the work using a text editor, but obviously, the best option is doing this entirely with a script. Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: why printing instead of turning that into the dictionary you're asking for?

Comment: @Sayse, That's what I've tried but I don't know how to do it, This is the reason for posted it here. Maybe it requires a little changed in the code but I've tried hours without achieving it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

tribunals = open('tribunals.json',encoding='utf-8')
tribunals = json.load(tribunals)

result = {}

for tribunal in tribunals:
    result[tribunal['city']] = {}
    for item in tribunal['tribunals']:
        result[tribunal['city']][item['name']] = item['value']

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I'm wanted!